# How to scale and weight a list of numbers where lower is better

Tags: functions

I am looking at the beaten margins in a horse race. As you can see from the table below the finishing order and the the corresponding margin. EG 2nd place finished 0.5 lengths behind first place.

```
   Margin
1    0
2    0.5
3    3
4    5.2
5    6
6    8
7    8.1
8    9
9    13
10   25
```

I am trying to scale these margins into a number where I can use it to boost overall performance weighting. Does anyone have an idea on the best way to scale this?

**EDIT** I have a ratings system already so hoping to add this function to it so that `margin` of `0` equals a weighting of `1` with decreasing margins and decreasing ratings. I have been using:

```
weighting = 1 - (margin/100)
```

I realise 100 is an arbitrary number but wanted to know if anyone else has any better ideas.

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So how I see this is, that you want to calculate some weight as a function of the margin. So 
$$
\text{weight} = f(\text{margin})
$$
, right? And you wan it to be a decreasing function, so that 
$$
m_1 < m_2  \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(m_1)> f(m_2)
$$
What other requirements do you need for this function? If you don't mention any other requirements, you could as well set
$$
\text{weight} = - \text{margin}
$$
As this fulfills both of the requirements.

Comment: thanks @MattiP.! yes I have thought about this but I would  somehow like to normalise it also as to not affect the overall rating as much (eg `margin of 0 = 1`). The other option is to include an arbitrary number for ever `1` length margin

Comment: added more detail to OP @MattiP.

Comment: So it's still not clear what you mean by "a better idea" because I don't know what you're trying to optimize here. So the best I can do is to give random ideas. Here's another random idea: Perhaps you want the scales to be between 0 and 1, so that the margin=0 gets a weight of 1 and the maximum margin gets the weight 0? Then you'd get the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{\text{max} - x}{\text{max}}
$$
where max is the largest margin (max=25) in your example. Now you have $f(0)=1$ and $f(25)=0$. Ta-daa!

Comment: great! thanks very much I think that might do the job!